# Logcheck Frequency Changes

Tags: linux, debian-based

I've got a logcheck running on my private server going through my logs for possible errors. I'm wondering if it's possible to make it so that if logcheck finds an error it first sends a notification like every five minutes but after a certain amount of time it changes to a daily message?

I know how to change the frequency of the normal check up but I'm not sure if it's possible to have this special rule.